# Safely using existing vs2010 sp1 after installing vs2012/13

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, backwards-compatibility

I have researched the topic and discovered that:

- You can install vs2012/13 on the same machine running vs2010 sp1
- You can target .NET framework 4.0 for your current projects and run them locally

The problem arises when you deploy your websites to servers that do not have fixes to bugs in .NET 4.0 that were made when installing .NET framework 4.5 on the local machine.

My question is, what is the best way I can make sure I can do the following using the same machine:

- I can still run my old/current vs2010 sp1 projects without breaking locally or when deployed remotely
- I can create new solutions using vs2010 sp1 targeting the .NET4.0 framework safely
- I can create new solutions using vs2012/13

If I cannot have the scenario above, would using Visual Studio Online help? (I have not had much to read on Visual Studio Online) but just thought that it could be an alternative to the above?

Comment: It's not clear what you're talking about. What do you think breaks in these situations? My understanding is that installing .NET 4.5 fixes some bugs in .NET 4.0, so if you test a .NET 4.0 program on a server that has .NET 4.5 installed, there may be certain bugs that would have happened on .NET 4.0 that won't happen anymore. The solution is to always test in the environment you'll be running in. In this case, you need to test on a pure .NET 4.0 system if that's where you'll be deploying to.

Comment: Hi John, that is the point, the server will not have .NET 4.5 installed, it will have 4.0. I need to start developing using vs2012 and .NET 4.5 for other new projects but I am afraid that the fixes that Microsoft made to the framework only lives on my machine, so that when i deploy older projects (.NET 4.0 projects) to client sites, it breaks remotely because the remote server does not have the fixes in place.

Comment: So, you should do your QA on a server that does not have the fixes installed. You can create a VM to do that. Azure VMs are pretty cheap if you remember to shut them down when you're not using them.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the help. The issue is that some sites are hosted on third party hosting company servers. I seem to have stumbled upon a link that suggests that the problem was with .NET 4.5 beta: http://forums.asp.net/t/1965084.aspx?Installing+Visual+Studio+2010+Professional+and+Visual+Studio+2012+Express+Side+by+Side

Comment: What issue? Have you _seen_ this issue or are you just reading about it?

Comment: I have been reading about it. I want to be cautious before installing vs2012/13 on my local machine before causing any havoc on my existing projects

Comment: There is no serious issue. Just make sure you always test code the way it will run in production. If your code will be running on "pure" .NET 4.0 boxes, then test it on a pure .NET 4.0 box, perhaps in addition to testing on your local, .NET 4.5 box.